# External display sabotages LUKS decryption

Tags: grub2, display, encryption, luks

Out of the blue my LUKS password of my Ubuntu installation (A) wasn't recognized anymore with

```
No key available with this passphrase
```

However another Ubuntu system (B) on the same Notebook decrypted just fine with the same password. (There is also a Windows system working fine.)

Also the Ubuntu A partition could be decrypted just fine from the Ubuntu B system with the correct password. Ubuntu A also successfully decrypted via Protected Mode.

After checking caps lock, trying to change the password to something simple as *00000000*, checking the keymap for grub for correct German keyboard layout, typing the password like US layout, running `update-initramfs` and `update-grub` all unsuccessful I had a really stupid idea: the only thing I changed with the setup was a new external Dell display that I had connected to the laptop via HDMI. So I detached it and suddenly the password was accepted immediately. I can now somewhat reliably reproduce the behavior that LUKS fails to decrypt the system whenever the display is connected right from startup. However one time it worked with the connected display. After bootup I can connect the display.

So my question is: What the Heck?

For the question why everything works fine with Ubuntu B:

- both have different Grub2 bootloaders
- LUKS GUI doesn't work in Ubuntu A, I only get terminal for password prompt, don't know why, never bothered

Does anyone have an idea what could lead to such a strange behavior?

Comment: Wow, can I just nominate this for the "World's Weirdest Bug" award? I'm guessing the problem lies in Plymouth (the thing that shows the bootup screen), but wow.

Comment: It's definitely in the top 10. Maybe there is some hardware fingerprint cryptsetup or plymouth rely on? Or the Dell display has some kind of own storage mounted to the system that messes up the device list of LUKS? I can only guess.

I decided to file a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1981904